# SSRS Report Exporting to PDF with Hard Page Breaks in middle of page

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, report, builder

When I use PDF export there are hard page breaks right in the middle of each page.  I don't think that it has to do with any particular grouping function such as 'keep together' because the page break is consistent on each page.  I have made sure that the body + margins < page size.  I have tried changing the interactive page size to 0, 0.  I am not sure what I should do at this point.  It just seems that the 'page area' when on the pdf is significantly less than the actual page size.  I fixed the issue as it concerns width by making my tables wider (but staying within the correct work space), but similar adjustments do not help with the height size of page for the pdf.

Comment: The interactive size only affects on-screen rendering. Check the page sizes on both the body and the report objects. Also check they are using the same unit of measure. I've had strange things happen when some parts of the report were Metric and other using Imperial units.

Comment: Thank you.  I made sure the page sizes on both the body any report match, both in values and units.  I do have subreports in this report, but they are not getting cut off in any meaningful way other than what appears to be a hard page break in the middle of the page.  I have a footer for this report and it pulls the footer up half way up the page as well.

Comment: if you export to Word, does it still do the same?

Comment: It looks great in Word. No blank white pages and no weird page breaks. It looks just as it should.

Comment: Very odd. CN yiu try this from another pc? Or can you deploy the report and try it.

Comment: I cannot try it on another pc.  I do have it deployed and this is the same issue.

Comment: I ended up fixing this issue with reducing the blank work space.  I had already done this without it working, so I believe it was fixed by reducing the work space in conjunction with another setting I must have changed in between both times I reduced it while playing around trying to fix it.